# Не работают CSS стили в Django

Tags: html, css, python, django

Только начал изучать *Django* и столкнулся с проблемой: не применяются стили *CSS* ни на одной из страниц (*home.html* и *about.html*).

файл *style.css*:

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
}
```

файл *base.html*:

```html
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'CSS/style.css' %}">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{% block title %} PAGE TITLE {% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SubFanTV</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      {% block li_home %}<li class="nav-item">{% endblock %}
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      {% block li_about %}<li class="nav-item">{% endblock %}
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Navbar ends -->

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Файл *home.html*:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}SubFanTV{% endblock %}
{% block li_home %}<li class="nav-item active">{% endblock %}



{% block content %}

<h1>HOME PAGE!!!</h1>





{% endblock %}
```

Файл *about.html*:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block li_about %}<li class="nav-item active">{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>ABOUT PAGE</h1>






{% endblock %}
```

Вот мои настройки в settings.py связанные со static.

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]`

Вот расположение файлов:
[image: Расположение файлов]

Вот что показывает Developer tools:[image: developer tools]

Comment: А что показывает Developer tools? Файлы грузятся корректно?

Comment: Прикрепил скрин в описании

Comment: В Devtools видно, что `background-color` переопределяется в `_reboot.scss` (он, кстати, нигде в приведенных листингах явно не подключен) — если вы проскроллите вниз, то увидите, что `background-color` из `style.css` зачёркнуто.

Comment: Выход — вам нужно подключить ваш `style.css` последним, чтобы он переопределял заданные ранее свойства

Comment: Сработало!!!Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

В Devtools видно, что background-color переопределяется в _reboot.scss (он, кстати, нигде в приведенных листингах явно не подключен) — если вы проскроллите вниз, то увидите, что background-color из style.css зачёркнуто.
Выход — вам нужно подключить ваш style.css последним, чтобы он переопределял заданные ранее свойства.

За ответ в коментах спасибо Artem Korsunov